# Java - IF statement after While loop not working

Tags: java, if-statement

Thanks guys, and, new problem arises.

Even if the list and user input is correct, it will still print out `"Your movie or/and theatre cannot be found."`

Things that I have found out about the problem. When there is 1 item in either one of the list (movie 0-1 item & theatre 0-1 item), it will not print out `"Your movie or/and theatre cannot be found."`

But when there is more than 1 item in either 1 of them (movie 1 item & theatre 2 or movie 2 & theatre 1), it will print out the `if(found == false)` statement.

```
public void addScreening(){
    System.out.println("-ADD NEW SCREENING-");
    String mTitle = Helper.readString("Enter movie title > ");
    String tName = Helper.readString("Enter theatre name > ");

    boolean found = true;

    while(found == true){
    for (int i = 0; i < movies.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < theatres.size(); j++) {
            if ((movies.get(i).getTitle().contains(mTitle) || mTitle.contains(movies.get(i).getTitle())) && 
                    (theatres.get(j).getName().contains(tName) || tName.contains(theatres.get(j).getName()))) {

                int year = Helper.readInt("Enter year > ");
                int month = Helper.readInt("Enter month > ");
                int day = Helper.readInt("Enter day > ");
                int hour = Helper.readInt("Enter hour > ");
                int min = Helper.readInt("Enter min > ");

                screenings.add(new MovieScreening(Helper.thisDate(year,
                        month, day, hour, min), movies.get(i),theatres.get(j), 0));
                System.out.println("Added successfully");

        }else if((!movies.get(i).getTitle().contains(mTitle) || !mTitle.contains(movies.get(i).getTitle())) 
                || (!theatres.get(j).getName().contains(tName) || !tName.contains(theatres.get(j).getName()))){

        found = false;

    }
        }

    }break;
    }if (found == false){
    System.out.println("Your movie or/and theatre cannot be found.");
    found = true;
    }
}
```

output

```
-ADD NEW SCREENING-
Enter movie title > 3
Enter theatre name > 3
Enter year > 3
Enter month > 3
Enter day > 3
Enter hour > 3
Enter min > 3
Added successfully
Your movie or/and theatre cannot be found.
```

Comment: `if (found = false)` should be `if (found == false)` or even better `if (!found)`

Comment: `=` assigns, `==` compares.

Comment: Never compare a boolean value to `true` or `false`. Just use it as-is.

Comment: But this is not the cause of error.

Comment: Maybe you should do `found = false` once again somewhere if this condition **is also not met**:

                `} else if ((!movies.get(i).getTitle().contains(mTitle) || !mTitle.contains(movies.get(i).getTitle()))
                        || (!theatres.get(j).getName().contains(tName) || !tName.contains(theatres.get(j).getName()))) {

                    found = false;

                }`

Comment: I have tried added else {found = false;} after the else if, but still have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Simply change

```
if (found = false)
```

to

```
if (found == false)

//OR

if (!found)
```

You were using assignment operator (`=`) instead of comparison (`==`). This is a common typo and in many cases it is easiest to use these formats.

```
if (found) {}  // if (found == true)
if (!found) {} // if (found == false)
```

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
  if (found = false){
```

to this:

```
  if (found == false){
```

Comment: No, change it to `if (!found) {`.  Comparing booleans to `true` or `false` is always asking for trouble.

Comment: what?  that's ridiculous.  comparing to == false is not negative logic.

Comment: It's redundant and, as you can see from the post, increases the possibility of error. In languages that treat zero as false and non-zero as true, comparisons like `if (var == true)` tend to produce unexpected behavior that's hard to detect. Comparing boolean values to either `true` or `false` is bad practice at best. If you absolutely _must_ do that because of some as-yet undiagnosed psychiatric condition, protect yourself against errors by using Yoda conditions.

Comment: not in my experience, this is your opinion and when dealing with the real world that have DB's designed by business people that have names like "Ineligible" or "Inactive" where I see logic that I didn't write but have to support with "if (Ineligible != false)" compared to positive logic of "if ( Ineligible == true)" or even "if Ineligible == false" is a bit easier to follow than "if (!inEligible)".