# Check for Empty EditText fails

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, string

I've tried everything from matching strings, to using TextUtils.isEmpty. No matter what I do, b is always true (even when edittext is purposely left blank) which allows the code to proceed to the next steps (this is a Madlib app).

If anybody can see why the code isn't properly checking for blank edittext's and displaying the Please Fill In All Fields" toast when one is blank, it would be very appreciated. Thanks. Sorry for the messy code.

```
public class Madlibs extends Fragment {


    switch (((MainActivity) getActivity()).getStory()) {
    case 0:
        output.setText(Stories[0]);
        title = Titles[0];
        actionBar.setTitle(title);
        editTextNumber = 12;

        addEdit = new BootstrapEditText[editTextNumber];
        for (int i = 0; i < addEdit.length; i++) {
            addEdit[i] = new BootstrapEditText(getActivity());
            l_layout.addView(addEdit[i]);
            params.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 20);
            addEdit[i].setLayoutParams(params);
            addEdit[i].setId(i);
        }
        addEdit[0].setHint("Name of Sickness");
        addEdit[1].setHint("Adjective");
        addEdit[2].setHint("Name of Boy");
        addEdit[3].setHint("Body Part");
        addEdit[4].setHint("Color");
        addEdit[5].setHint("Animal");
        addEdit[6].setHint("Article of Clothing");
        addEdit[7].setHint("Relative");
        addEdit[8].setHint("Adjective");
        addEdit[9].setHint("Article of Clothing");
        addEdit[10].setHint("Body Part");
        addEdit[11].setHint("Number");

        break;
    case 1:
        // fragment = new Madlibs();
        break;
    case 2:
        // fragment = new MadlibsSaved();
    }

    convert = (BootstrapButton) view.findViewById(R.id.convert);
    convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int i;
            String s;

            for (i = 0; i < addEdit.length; i++) {
                s = addEdit[i].getText().toString().trim();

                if (s.isEmpty() || s.length() == 0 || s.equals("") || s == null) {
                    b = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    b = true;
                }
            }
            if (b = true) {
                gather();
                postIt();
                outputText = output.getText().toString();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Fill In All Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
if (b = true) { // HERE
    gather();
    postIt();
    outputText = output.getText().toString();
}
```

You are using `b = true` which sets b to true, and since you are able to do this successfully, the conditional evaluates to true every time. What you want instead is the comparison operator `==`

```
if (b == true) {
    gather();
    postIt();
    outputText = output.getText().toString();
}
```

or even better, since the variable you are comparing is a boolean, you could just use

```
if (b) {}  //This is "if b is true..."
if (!b) {} //This is "if b is false..."
```

You can see another one of my answers about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356277/java-if-statement-after-while-loop-not-working/21356308#21356308).

Comment: MY GOD I AM STUPID! I was looking over my code hundreds of times and I missed an extra "=". Thank you for finding that! @Takendarkk

Comment: Sure thing. Fresh eyes always help.

Comment: tell me about it...Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

```
        for (i = 0; i < addEdit.length; i++) {
            s = addEdit[i].getText().toString().trim();
            if (s.isEmpty() || s.length() == 0 || s.equals("") || s == null) {
                b = false;
            }
            else {
                b = true;
            }
        }
```

For Loop ends here and the following is outside the For Loop :

```
        if (b = true) {
            gather();
            postIt();
            outputText = output.getText().toString();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please Fill In All Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
```

**Problem 1 :**

```
if(b == true) {

}
```

**Problem 2 :**

Now, suppose edittext 1 is empty, b is set to true but then it'll straightaway move ahead in the loop to edittext 2 to the last edittext which are not empty hence it'll set b to false again. You'll need to put the check inside the for loop.

Comment: I didn't downvote...but you are right just like the other user! I can't believe I forgot the extra = sign. Thank you for finding those problems!