# Number and loop issue

Tags: java

I am new to programming and am having difficulty with this problem. I am trying to build a wall based on the number entered in the JTextField but the number cannot exceed 20. I cannot get my error message to display nor can I get my brick wall to build. Could someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
public class Wall extends JApplet implements ActionListener {

JTextField enter;
Boolean submit;
JLabel bricks;
JButton build;
JPanel top;
Image zombie;
int value;

public void init() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    top = new JPanel();
    build = new JButton("AHHHHHH...ZOMBIES!");                          //button for building wall
    bricks = new JLabel("Enter between 1 & 20 rows to contruct:");
    enter = new JTextField(2);

    top.add(build);         //add zombie button
    top.add(bricks);        //add intructions
    top.add(enter);         //add text field
    add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    build.addActionListener(this);


}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if (ae.getSource() == build) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(build.getText());
        if (value > 0 && value < 21) {
            submit = true;
            repaint();
        } else {
            submit = false;
            repaint();
        }

    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    //add zombie image
    Image zombie = getImage(getCodeBase(), "Zombie.jpg");
    g.drawImage(zombie, 0, 45, this);

    if (submit = false) //add error message
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 40));
        g.drawString("You must enter a number between 1 & 20!", 400, 100);  //add message
    }

    int brick_width = 50;
    int brick_height = 20;
    int spacing = 1;
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 21) {
        drawBrick(g, nextInt(brick_width + spacing), nextInt(brick_height + spacing));
        x = x + getWidth() + 50;
        x = x - 25 + getWidth() + 50;
        x++;

    }

}

public void drawBrick(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    g.setColor(new Color(150, 0, 0));
        g.fillRect(0, 635, 50, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (submit = false)` should be `if (submit == false)` First one is assignment, second one is comparison.

Comment: @Takendarkk Furthermore, it is probably simpler to just do if (!submit) ;)

Comment: Yes, check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21356277/java-if-statement-after-while-loop-not-working/21356308#21356308)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of painting on [top-level containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) such as `JApplet` directly, you have to use `JPanel` and paint on it. Just override `paintComponent()` method of `JPanel()`. Never forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)` in overridden method.

sample code:

```
top = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ...
        // your custom painting code goes here
    }
};
```

**Note:**

`submit == false` and `!submit` are the correct way to check it but it still will result in `NullPointerException` because you have never initialized instance variable `submit`.

Use primitive `boolean` instead of `Boolean` to avoid such exception or initialize it properly.

```
Boolean submit = false;
```

Comment: No, a `Boolean` or an additional state variable is needed, since there are really three states: before the user has entered a value, an invalid value, or a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statement to: 
    `if (submit == false)`
That'll get your error message to pop up

Comment: result in `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Should be  if (submit == false) rather than if (submit = false).

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I can now get the error message to display but it does it all the time when I run the applet. I only want it to display if the value entered at the top is greater than 20.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1) Your submit variable is not initialized, you should initialize it to true/false.
If you dont want to initialize it, you can simple try with

```
if(submit!=null && !submit)
```

2)
Secondly, **"="** is used for assigning a value where as **"=="** is used for comparing
Change

```
if (submit = false) //add error message
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 40));
        g.drawString("You must enter a number between 1 & 20!", 400, 100);  //add message
    }
```

to

```
if (submit == false) //add error message
    {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 40));
        g.drawString("You must enter a number between 1 & 20!", 400, 100);  //add message
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

To solve your error display issue,

`submit = false`  should be `submit == false`

`=`  is for assignment

`==` is for comparison

Also, initialize your variable to avoid null pointer exception:

`boolean submit = false;`

Comment: @Braj: Yeah got it! I thought if actionPerformed is called before paint method, it is not required. I don't know japlets. so forgive me  if I am blatantly wrong :D

Comment: I tested the code then after I find out this issue.